# I am not able to insert values into a mysql table using python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Here's the code:

```
   a1 = input('Index : ')
   b1 = input('Name : ')
   c1 = input('job : ')

   sql3 = 'Insert into data(index,name,job) values(%s, %s, %s)'
   val3 = [a1,b1,c1]
   cursor.execute(sql3,val3)
   mydb.commit()
   for x in cursor:
       print(x)
```

I have entered the values as follows:

a=3

b=sam

c=singer

And i'm getting this error:

```
ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index,name,phone_no) values('3', 'sam', 'singer')' at line 1
```

Please help me with this..

P.S: Please don't judge me by this question, I am trying to learn these codes myself...

Comment: Did you create the table data in mysql with those columns?

Answer (score 2):

For [`executemany`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) `val3` should be a list of list, like this

```
sql3 = 'INSERT INTO data(index,name,phone_no) VALUES (%s, "%s", "%s")'
val3 = [[a1,b1,c1]] # val shoul be a list of list
cursor.executemany(sql3,val3)
```

If you have one set of values I would suggest to use `cursor.execute`,

```
sql3 = f'INSERT INTO data (index,name,phone_no) VALUES ({a1}, "{b1}", "{c1}")'
cursor.execute(sql3)
```

Without `f-string`,

```
sql3 = 'INSERT INTO data(index,name,phone_no) VALUES (%s, "%s", "%s")'
val3 = (a1,b1,c1) # val shoul be a list of list
cursor.executemany(sql3, val3)
```

Comment: but i'm still getting errors

Comment: ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index,name,phone_no) values('9', 'sam', '34565653')' at line 1

Comment: @Thakshaya Please check with my updated code.

Comment: Please don't teach newbees to create SQL statements with f-strings (or similar mechanism). It works for their purpose but sooner or later they will write code that is prone to SQL-injection vulnaribilites.

Comment: i have another query too. If we have to insert date into MySQL table through python what is the format? is it YYYY/MM/DD or DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: @Thakshaya Please post another question. It will be harder to explain here. And there might be more experts who can solve those most efficient methods.